# Bias and variance estimation with boostrap

Tags: variance, bootstrap, bias, resampling

The Wikipedia article about [Jacknife estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackknife_%28statistics%29) of the bias and variance of an estimator $\theta$ includes the following formulas:

**Variance** of $\theta$:

$
\operatorname {Var}(\theta )=\sigma ^{2}={\frac  {n-1}{n}}\sum _{{i=1}}^{n}({\bar  {\theta }}_{i}-{\bar  {\theta }}_{{\mathrm  {Jack}}})^{2}$

where ${\bar  {\theta }}_{{Jack}}={\frac  {1}{n}}\sum _{{i=1}}^{n}({\bar  {\theta }}_{i})$ is the jacknife estimator.

**Bias-correction** of $\theta$:

$
{\bar  {\theta }}_{{\mathrm  {BiasCorrected}}}=N{\bar  {\theta }}-(N-1){\bar  {\theta }}_{{Jack}}
$

---

My question is: What are the corresponding formulas for bootstrap? Are they different?

Comment: Shao, Jun. “Bootstrap Variance and Bias Estimation in Linear Models.” The Canadian Journal of Statistics / La Revue Canadienne De Statistique, vol. 16, no. 4, 1988, pp. 371–382. JSTOR, JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/3314934.

Answer (score 2):

I think the formulas for Bootstrap are as follows, although I can't seem to find a proper reference:

Let $h = \frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^{K}{\hat{y}_k}$ 
be the mean predicted outcome from the $K$ bootstrap resamples.

Then:

- Bias is $y - h$
- Variance is $\frac{1}{K-1}\sum_{k=1}^{K} (y_k - h)^2$

Comment: Your bias is different from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129478/when-is-the-bootstrap-estimate-of-bias-valid