# How to infer correlation of population from correlation of samples without assuming normality?

Tags: correlation, bootstrap, bias, pearson-r

There are very large number of data points ($\sim 10^{100}$), which form a (discrete) joint distribution $(X,Y)$, where $X,Y$ are discrete random variables. Note that we have no knowledge of these distributions. We sample a small number $n$ of data points randomly, and we can calculate Pearson correlation coefficient $\rho_s$ of the samples. Then, how can I infer the PCC $\rho_p$ of the population? In general, what is the relation between $\rho_s$, $\rho_p$, and $n$? If I sample, say, $100n$ data points, then does the sample have PCC close to $\rho_p$? We can assume none of the above distribution to be normal. Can we say anything interesting if we assume $n$ to be less than 20 (if not 50)?

Edit: If you think PCC is not very useful for the case one cannot assume normality of distribution, you can use other quantities such as Spearman's R instead.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're asking sampling from a large finite population that is itself drawn from $(X, Y)$, instead of sampling from $(X, Y)$ directly? Also, is the sample size $n$ or $100n$? Also, are you trying to say that $(X, Y)$ **might not** be bivariate normal, or that it **must not** be bivariate normal?

Comment: There are very large number of data points with x- and y-components. The distribution of these data is unknown, and hence their component-wise distribution $X$ and $Y$ are also unknown. In particular, $X,Y,(X,Y)$ are not necessarily normal, but it's possible that they are. I want to know how PCC can be compared for two cases where the sample size is $n$ and $100n$, respectively.

Comment: Why do you use $\sigma$ for Pearson correlation in population? This is normally used for standard deviation and could be confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing. As I'm from different field, I'm unfamiliar with the convention used in statistics. I changed the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but: if $n$ is reasonably large (and in your case there is no need to choose a small $n$), so think (at least $n=1000$ or $n=10000$). In that case the sample pearson correlation should be approximately unbiased, unless the data distribution is very different than gaussian. But you don't need to assume that, [you cane estimate the bias using bootstrapping](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129478/when-is-the-bootstrap-estimate-of-bias-valid).

Then, for sample size $100 n$, the bias should be smaller, but how much smaller?  You could just investigate that also with the bootstrap.